Gradle make project ins android studio shows "Duplicate class found" error: lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop conflicts with lifecycle-viewmodel-android
I was adding some new functionality to one of my Legacy projects. Meanwhile, I started to use ViewModelProvider in my project which android studio suggested to add required dependencies for it:
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

and it also added some dependencies to my application Gradle files.
After this change, when I try to make my project it shows error that prompts "Duplicate class found".
Here is the build errors:
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy$1 found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Companion found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$OnRequeryFactory found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviderGetKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras$Empty found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras$Key found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.InitializerViewModelFactory found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.InitializerViewModelFactoryBuilder found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.InitializerViewModelFactoryKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.MutableCreationExtras found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelFactoryDsl found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelInitializer found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.CloseableCoroutineScope found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.CloseableCoroutineScopeKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.DefaultViewModelProviderFactory found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.JvmViewModelProviders found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.SynchronizedObject found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.SynchronizedObjectKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.SynchronizedObject_jvmKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.ViewModelImpl found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.ViewModelProviders found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.ViewModelProviders$ViewModelKey found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.internal.ViewModelProviders_jvmKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop-2.8.0 (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0) and jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-release-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

I also tried to find which packages lead to this conflict since I never used lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0 in my project but I could not imagine that.
I executed gradlew.bat androidDependencies and here is its outputs:
6:14:50 PM: Executing 'androidDependencies'...

Executing tasks: [androidDependencies] in project W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2


> Task :app:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\java-websocket-1.3.0.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\platform_sdk_v2.3.706.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\Sewoo_Android_1109.jar
+--- androidx.databinding:viewbinding:8.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0@aar
+--- com.github.ekimual:magic-toast:0.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6@aar
+--- androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.transition:transition:1.2.0@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-jvm:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-desktop:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.2.0@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.2.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.7.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4@aar
+--- androidx.resourceinspection:resourceinspection-annotation:1.0.1@jar
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9@jar
+--- org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12@jar
\--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6@jar

debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\java-websocket-1.3.0.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\platform_sdk_v2.3.706.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\Sewoo_Android_1109.jar
+--- androidx.databinding:viewbinding:8.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0@aar
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4@aar
+--- com.github.ekimual:magic-toast:0.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9@jar
+--- org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6@aar
+--- androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0@aar
+--- androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.transition:transition:1.2.0@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-jvm:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-desktop:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6@jar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.resourceinspection:resourceinspection-annotation:1.0.1@jar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.3.0@aar
+--- androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.2.0@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.2.0@jar
+--- androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0@jar
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-core:1.0.4@jar
+--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.15.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.7.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.8.0@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0@jar
\--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0@jar

release
releaseCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\java-websocket-1.3.0.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\platform_sdk_v2.3.706.jar
+--- W:\_Sources\_Android\PJ\SF\PJ2\app\libs\Sewoo_Android_1109.jar
+--- androidx.databinding:viewbinding:8.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0@aar
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4@aar
+--- com.github.ekimual:magic-toast:0.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9@jar
+--- org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6@aar
+--- androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.transition:transition:1.2.0@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.1.0@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-jvm:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-desktop:2.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.0@aar
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6@jar
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.2.0@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.2.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.8.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.7.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.22@jar
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.resourceinspection:resourceinspection-annotation:1.0.1@jar

[I trimmed some parts due to post size limit]


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 500ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed

Build Analyzer results available
6:14:51 PM: Execution finished 'androidDependencies'.

The thing that I cannot understand is where the namespace lifecycle-viewmodel-desktop:2.8.0 inserted into my application and how can I fix this duplicate class issue?
I also attached my dependencies for your reference:
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'com.github.ekimual:magic-toast:0.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/java-websocket-1.3.0.jar');

    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar') {
        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'

        }
    }


}

And here is the dependencies in project level build.gradle file:
dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0')
    //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
    //classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'

    // Add the dependency for the Performance Monitoring plugin
    //classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'  // Performance Monitoring plugin


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}


What happens when you remove the androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0 dependency? You shouldn't ever be depending on -android artifacts directly

@ianhanniballake issue resolved :) So why the name is so confusing? androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.0? So where -android should be used?

As explained in the Lifecycle 2.8.0 release notes, Lifecycle now ships artifacts that are compatible with Kotlin Multiplatform.
With how Kotlin Multiplatform artifacts are published, there is a single top level artifact - in your case, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel - this is what you need to define in your build.gradle file as explained in the Lifecycle Declaring Dependencies section.
The Kotlin plugin is the only thing that looks at platform specific artifacts (like the lifecycle-viewmodel-android artifact), including those only when necessary. Therefore you should remove any -android artifacts you've specifically added.

I am using '    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.7.0'
' libraries in my Android Java project. How to move it to 2.8.0 libraries!? I have a message from compiler: ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl)' has private access in 'androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.

@isabsent - it sounds like you should create your own question. You can provide a link to it here if you'd like.

I have created it - Compiler error migrating to androidx.lifecycle 2.8.0 library
